# Problems comparing two strings in C (Segmentation fault) Core dumped

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf

I've created a `struct` to group two pointer variables so I can store the address on those. Then I'm instantiating the struct and referring to the two variables from the `main` contest.
Comparing the two strings based on useroutput and return the desired result.

The code is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    char *name2;
} names;

int main()
{
    names nm;
    printf("Please enter first string: ");
    scanf("%s", nm.name)
    printf("Please enter second string: ");
    scanf("%s", nm.name2);

    if(strcmp(nm.name, nm.name2) == 0)
        printf("Strings %s and %s do match\n", nm.name, nm.name2);  
    else
        printf("Strings %s and %s do not match\n", nm.name, nm.name2);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to  `printf("%s", &nm.name);`

I am a novice C user.  Thanks!

Example that works without `struct` and pointer variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Please enter first string: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    char name2[20];
    printf("Please enter second string: ");
    scanf("%s", &name2);

    if(strcmp(name, name2) == 0)
        printf("Strings %s and %s do match\n", name, name2);    
    else
        printf("Strings %s and %s do not match\n", name, name2);
    return 0;
}




gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -pedantic -o strcmp strcmp.c 

strcmp.c: In function ‘main’:
strcmp.c:10:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat]
strcmp.c:11:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
strcmp.c:13:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat]
strcmp.c:15:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Comment: Again and again... you need to allocate memory first (for `name` and `name2`)

Comment: When you allocate memory you will also need to take care of buffer overflow problem. You can't just read into a buffer like scanf("%s", pointer);

Comment: `scanf` is dangerous, try `fgets`.

Comment: Guys, I am still not sure what you mean. I need just an example based on my code.  `char *name[20];` would maybe work but why. See my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **allocate memory** - this is a consensus here.

But no one pointed out to the **buffer overflow** problem. `scanf("%s", pointer);` may read more bytes than memory available in the buffer corrupting memory and causing program crush. Use **field width** specification to restrict number of characters to read:

```
char name[21];
scanf("%20s", name);
```

or if you want a dynamically allocated buffer

```
char *name = new char[21];
scanf("%20s", name);
```

The array must be **large enough** to accept all the sequence and the terminating NULL character. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

**Address**. You mentioned symbol &. This is an address operator. It is required in some examples you might have seen because `scanf()` expects a memory address.

```
int val;
scanf("%d", &val);
```

You are reading a string not an integer as in the example above

```
char name[21]; // name is an address of memory allocated for 21 bytes
char *name;    // same, name is an address, not allocated yet.
char name;     // is a char variable, it hols a single character.
               // If you need an address of the memory that holds that single character,
               // you need to use &
char *pointer  = &name; // Now pointer holds an address of name
```

**Please read more about memory** and variable declarations in C/C++. You wrote: `printf("%s", &nm.name);`
That will attempt to print a random memory area. If you are lucky it'll print garbage, if not it'll crash your program with memory access violation.

**nm** is a struct, **name** is a pointer to a character array. **nm.name** is a pointer to the character array. **&nm.name** is a pointer to the pointer to the array but `printf` interprets that as a pointer to the array.

Answer (score 2):

For your edited question, you are using `scanf` incorrectly:

```
scanf("%s", &name);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

You must have seen examples using `scanf` with `&`, but in this case, `name` is already an `char [20]`, which decays into a `char *` when passing as function argument.

Comment: How is that? I've learned that when user input is expected, then the variable  should get an  ampersand `&` sign in front.  Maybe I don't understand it yet.. but what if I add `&` or remove it?

Comment: @holasz : you need to learn how to input strings from the standard input .

Comment: @holasz `&` is the address-of operator, when you have an `int a`, and `scanf` format is `%d`, it expects a `int *` type, that's why you have to pass `&a`. But for `name`, it's a `char` array, which will decay into a `char *`, which is already what the `%s` format expects.

Comment: @Yu Hao, sheshe!  I now understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the pointers point to something, for example:

```
int main()
{
    char buff1[20];
    char buff2[20];
    names nm;
    nm.name = buff1;
    nm.name2 = buff2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the struct as below , your code will work fine .

```
 typedef struct
 {
   char name[20];
   char name2[20];
 }names;
```

Comment: Thanks, Though I *still wanted to use pointer variables like `*name[20]` and `*name2[20]` but I get the idea.

Comment: @holasz Did you mean `&name[0]`?

Comment: char *name[20] is an array of charecter pointers , that will not solve your problem.